# After deploying with mup app does not update

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I did some work on an app deployed by another developer. I ran mup setup and mup deploy using the 'config' option ('mup deploy --config .deploy/mup.js', it didn't work any other way). It looks like everything deployed successfully, no error messages. However, when I visit the site it still appears the same. Also, there is nothing in the server logs indicating an issue. (I ran 'docker logs -t app'). I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

**.deploy/mup.js**

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '100.000.00.00',
      username: 'root',
      password: 'password123'
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'app',
    path: '..',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      debug: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://100.000.00.00',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },
    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

**server log**  (everything logged in docker container since the date I deployed)

```
2016-11-14T14:40:34.342355688Z
2016-11-14T14:40:34.344602204Z > meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server
2016-11-14T14:40:34.344624825Z > node npm-rebuild.js
2016-11-14T14:40:34.344632219Z
2016-11-14T14:40:35.382894981Z
2016-11-14T14:40:35.382987103Z > bcrypt@0.8.7 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
2016-11-14T14:40:35.382998724Z > node-gyp rebuild
2016-11-14T14:40:35.383026146Z
2016-11-14T14:40:36.580919332Z make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
2016-11-14T14:40:36.584207868Z   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
2016-11-14T14:40:37.075750622Z   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
2016-11-14T14:40:37.266834696Z   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
2016-11-14T14:40:39.732683391Z   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
2016-11-14T14:40:39.800807437Z   COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
2016-11-14T14:40:39.808748112Z make: Leaving directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
2016-11-14T14:40:39.877493669Z bcrypt@0.8.7 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
2016-11-14T14:40:39.877567225Z bindings@1.2.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bindings
2016-11-14T14:40:39.877580282Z nan@2.3.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/nan
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699624606Z {
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699695343Z   "meteor-dev-bundle": "0.0.0",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699708887Z   "npm": "3.10.8",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699716022Z   "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699722640Z   "http_parser": "2.5.2",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699729518Z   "icu": "56.1",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699735920Z   "modules": "46",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699742081Z   "node": "4.4.7",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699748323Z   "openssl": "1.0.2h",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699754373Z   "uv": "1.8.0",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699781195Z   "v8": "4.5.103.36",
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699820569Z   "zlib": "1.2.8"
2016-11-14T14:40:40.699828508Z }
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894107705Z meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894184247Z +-- node-gyp@3.4.0
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894202069Z | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.10
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894208434Z | +-- npmlog@3.1.2
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894214346Z | | +-- are-we-there-yet@1.1.2
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894220339Z | | | `-- readable-stream@2.2.2
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894226099Z | | `-- gauge@2.6.0
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894231786Z | |   `-- string-width@1.0.2
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894237330Z | |     `-- code-point-at@1.1.0
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894262594Z | +-- path-array@1.0.1
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894269859Z | | `-- array-index@1.0.0
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894275706Z | |   `-- debug@2.3.2
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894281320Z | |     `-- ms@0.7.2
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894286912Z | +-- request@2.78.0
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894292594Z | | `-- form-data@2.1.2
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894298383Z | `-- which@1.2.12
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894303892Z `-- node-pre-gyp@0.6.29
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894309520Z   `-- tar-pack@3.1.4
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894315080Z     +-- debug@2.2.0
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894320560Z     | `-- ms@0.7.1
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894343548Z     `-- readable-stream@2.1.5
2016-11-14T14:40:40.894350463Z
2016-11-14T14:40:40.904904267Z npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
2016-11-14T14:40:40.905521216Z npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
2016-11-14T14:40:40.906073238Z npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
2016-11-14T14:40:40.926571001Z => Starting meteor app on port:80
```

**deploy process**

```
D:\Documents\Websites\app\app-master>mup deploy --config .deploy/mup.js --settings settings.json
  mup:module:default exec => mup deploy +0ms
  mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor deploy +5ms
  mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor push +5ms
Building App Bundle Locally

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor
[107.170.50.30] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server
  nodemiral:sess:107.170.50.30 copy file - src: D:\tmp\61b85e19-6efc-4be1-b96c-5fd100068f9c\bundle.tar.gz, dest: /opt/app/tmp/bundle.tar.gz, vars: undefined +0ms
[107.170.50.30] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server: SUCCESS
[107.170.50.30] - Pushing the Startup Script
  nodemiral:sess:107.170.50.30 copy file - src: C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup\lib\modules\meteor\assets\templates\start.sh, dest: /opt/app/config/start.sh, vars: {"appName":"app","useLocalMongo":1,"port":80,"logConfig":{"opts":{"max-size":"100m","max-file":10}},"docker":{"image":"abernix/meteord:base","imageFrontendServer":"meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server"}} +7.8m
[107.170.50.30] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
  mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor envconfig +9m
```

Comment: whats the output of `mup logs -f` ?

Comment: Well that doesn't even work it just says, '(app name)' is not a docker command. I'll put up the result of running 'docker logs' via server. Posted above.

Comment: weird. what happens if you run `mup stop`? Are you sure you access the app you deploy? Maybe the old version is just running...

Comment: mup stop does nothing. I gave up and migrated to Galaxy.